# Find three non-independent events such as $P(A\cap B \cap C)=P(A) P(B)P(C)$

Tags: probability

The purpose of this exercise is to find 3 events $A,B,C$ such as $P(A\cap B \cap C)=P(A) P(B)P(C)$, but with the condition that $A,B$ and $C$ are not independent.

My problem concerns the definition of independence of events. I have understood that two events are independent if we have: $P(A\cap B)$=P(A)P(B), which leads to the same formula written in my exercise with 3 events. From there, I concluded that we can’t find those events, as it’s in conflict with the definition.

Could I have some explanations please, or a concret example?

Comment: Consider an example of $A,B$ not independent and $C=\emptyset$

Comment: If you don't like examples with empty events... consider the uniform distribution on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ (*equivalently, toss three fair coins*) and let $A=B=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and let $C=\{1,5,6,7\}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks for your answer. I didn’t understand the probability you’re using with your sets…

Comment: You don't know what the uniform distribution is?  I should think that is a far more critical thing for you to ask about if so... that should have been day-one material when studying probability.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, I do, but $P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=\frac{1}{8^4}$, and $P(A \cap B \cap C)=\frac{1}{8}$…

Comment: No... $\Pr(A)$ here is $\Pr(\{1,2,3,4\})$ is $\dfrac{\|\{1,2,3,4\}\|}{\|\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}\|} = \dfrac{4}{8}=\dfrac{1}{2}$...  How did you think it was $\dfrac{1}{8^4}$ rather than $\dfrac{4}{8}$?  Recall that "*or*" is related to addition... We are asking the probability of it being a $1$ *or* a $2$ *or* a $3$ *or* a $4$, so that is $\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8} = \frac{4}{8}$.  Multiplication and addition are different things used in different scenarios...

Comment: @JMoravitz I understood your example, as following: You choose randomly one of the eight numbers, four times, and you calculate the probability to obtain the number 1,2,3 and 4 for $P(A)$ for example, which gives you $\frac{1}{8}$ for each draw!

Comment: No.  This is you have a bag of eight balls... the balls numbered $1,2,3,4$ are colored red while the balls numbered $5,6,7,8$ are colored blue.  You draw one ball at random.  $\Pr(A)$ is asking "*what is the probability that the ball you pulled was red?*"  Now, remove the crutch of thinking of the balls as having been colored... $\Pr(A)$ is asking "*what is the probability that the ball you pulled was such that its numbers was any of $1,2,3,4$?*"  That is a probability of $\frac{4}{8}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Okay, that’s clear for me, thanks. But if you have to choose 3 events, you can’t take two same events, the purpose of the exercise is to find three events associated to a specific situation

Comment: "*you can't take two same events*"  Sure you can.  If you don't want two of the events to be the same... then I'm sure you can figure out how to modify my example to make $B$ different than $A$ while keeping the probabilities all the same.  I specifically took $A$ and $B$ to be the same since that is a simple example of two dependent events... the most extreme example of two dependent events.  If you want $A$ and $B$ to be different, then checking they are dependent can still be done but requires some effort to actually be expended.